# PHP - Handling social tracking strings being added to URLs after hash

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'm an intermediate PHP person and trying to handle URLs on a site that has hash tag sections on every page. Complicating this are social tracking strings that get added.

I need this:

```
http://myvenuesite.org/venues/venue-detail/index.php?venue=therockclub&gclid=CjwKCAjGJBhB1EiwACU1Aib_8tuyvRNc5kik6Ip4b_MK845Yug6pFu1D-Wd4qJ3gAa4MJOax8_BoCfCkQAvD_BwE#venue-details&mkt_campaign=2CUEQFFZ4PGDA2E98V7UZQ0T
```

to go here using PHP logic:

```
http://localhost:8000/venues/venue-detail/index.php?venue=therockclub#venue-details
```

Note the `#venue-details` hash that's buried in the first URL.

Basically, keep the **venue=therockclub** after the `?` and keep the **#venue-details** hash, but lose any and all the &params, at whatever position.

I'm also using redirect logic to give the client "vanity urls" so for example:

```
myvenuesite.org/therockclub
```

redirects to the full url:

```
http://myvenuesite.org/venues/venue-detail/index.php?venue=therockclub#venue-details
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ends up at the right place"? What wrong place do users who currently open those URLs end up at?

Comment: It depends on the routing system that you're using or if you're doing manually, can you share more about it?

Comment: 1. [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url) 2. Add the details you want. 3. `unparse_url()` which is in the top comment in the `parse_url()` docs.

Comment: Or if someone _else_ is sharing those broken URLs let them be broken and send them my advice on how to not do that.

Comment: @the_previ I rewrote the question with a specific URL.

Comment: @Sammitch -- I think I figured it out. Just need to pay attention to the interaction of PHP and JavaScript URL parsing and redirects and how they can concat and stack if not  careful.